# Sharing data between controllers

Tags: angularjs

I am making first steps in Angular.JS and faced the problem when variable available in scope is no longer available in router view. Setup is as follows:

```
var vApp = angular.module('appG', ['ngRoute', 'appG.directives'])
  .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/', {templateUrl: '/partials/form.html', controller: 'ctrlMain'})
        .when('/welcome', {templateUrl: '/partials/welcome.html', controller: 'ctrlMain'})
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
  });

validationApp.controller('ctrlMain', function($scope, $http, $location) {

$scope.user = {};

$scope.submitForm = function () {
    $http.post('/signup', $scope.user). 
      success(function(data) {
          $location.url('/welcome');
      });      
};

$scope.submitData = function () {
    if ($scope.signupForm.$valid) {
        $scope.submitForm();
    } else {
        $scope.signupForm.submitted = true;
    }    
};
```

});

HTML code:

```
  <html ng-app="appG">
      <div ng-controller="ctrlMain">
         <ng-view></ng-view>   
      </div> 

  </html>
```

form.htm (just part of it):

```
<form name="signupForm" id="signupForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
  <input type="text" class="text" ng-class="{'submit-error' : signupForm.submitted}" name="uFirst" placeholder="First name" ng-model="user.first" required/>
<a href="" class="native" ng-click="submitData()"><i class="fa fa-sign-in pull-left"></i>Submit</a>
</form>
```

welcome.html:

```
<p>{{user.first}}, thank you! </p>
```

Partial form.html contains form code with basic validation and works ok, partial welcome.html contain simple

with texts containing {{user.first}} (user has binding from form and name is a property of the user object. The problem is that {{user.first}} is always empty in welcome.html partial. I would appreciate any help to figure out how it is possible to pass value of the $scope.user to the second partial. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New scopes are created whenever you define a route/controller. Your two controllers have completely seperate `$scope` objects. In this case they're called "sibling" scopes. A variable defined in `ctrlMain` won't be available in `welcome` even though you use the same controller reference. The router is actually creating a fresh instance of `ctrlMain`.

The quick easy fix is to inject `$rootScope` and set `$rootScope.user` instead of `$scope.user`. `$rootScope` is a special scope that is the parent of all scopes. The values will be "inherited" by all child scopes in your entire app.

Obviously that's not that efficient and usually frowned upon, so the proper way is usually to use a service. You'll have to read up on creating a service, but you'd then inject the service and set your user object there. In fact, your HTTP stuff would go into the service as well.

Answer (score 0):

An option that I often use, which follows the same pattern as most server side MVC frameworks (like Rails) is to create a controller called 'ApplicatonController' , and set that on your body tag,  with  ***ng-controller="ApplicationController"***
Your MainCtrl will load inside the body tag, so it will inherit anything found in the parent controller.

It's called controller nesting.

You create a controller called "ApplicationController" as you have your MainCtrl, except now you can access properties and methods from the application controller from within the MainCtrl without the need to inject anything additional like $rootScope.

The hierarchy now goes

**$rootScope -> ApplicationController -> MainCtrl**

I find this approach is easier to wrap your head around if you're familiar with frameworks like Rails that follow the same structure.

I also like to avoid over confusing things by creating a service for everything, because you end up with huge dependency injection strings which become a hassle to manage.

Controller nesting is probably not going to be the most "Angular" way of doing it, but it solves your problem with minimal effort.

Comment: how would you fix this if you use routes instead of controller nesting in your view? Routes doesnt specifically allow you to have a parent Ctrl and a child ctrl.